# VSCode: "bash: EOL: command not found" on startup

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

On starting up VSCode (Mac), the integrated terminal shows the following being executed:

```
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash: EOL: command not found
bash-3.2$
```

I actually see each line being executed, but I can't work out what the source of this is.  I note that there are now 15 of them, but previously it used to be fewer. I don't know whether this relates to the number of extensions or not, but it's not the same number.

Is there any way I can see what this relates to, and if for example, it's a configuration issue or just a bug?

Jon

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you open a regular terminal in macOS?

Comment: No - this is specific to VSCode.  It's not like there is a .profile issue as far as I can tell